# Percentage based star rating doesn't show up correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm implementing percentage based star rating:

```js
var bvTireRating = 2.5;
var starRating = bvTireRating * 20;
$('.star-ratings-top').width(starRating + '%');
```

```css
.star-ratings {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  color: pink;
  font-size: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}

.star-ratings .star-ratings-top {
  color: gold;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.star-ratings .star-ratings-bottom {
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="star-ratings">
  <div class="star-ratings-top"><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span></div>
  <div class="star-ratings-bottom"><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span></div>
</div>
```

The output appears to not be correct, as the two layers do not match and the stars do not fill in accordingly to the percentage given:

[image]

Does somebody know how to solve it?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: [I can't reproduce the problem.](https://jsfiddle.net/95vzw7pd/) Can you help to clarify?

Comment: Your code sample looks fine. There must be some other CSS affecting your output.

Comment: https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/wmGeNX looks fine in codepen

Comment: `accordingly to the percentage given...` to fix this,  on your `.star-ratings` change the fixed width to `width: fit-content;`... about the layers, it appears to work very well for everybody here